# Ajax update do not render html

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<script>
    function fun() {
          $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_add_numbers', {}, function(data) {
            $("#totalprofit").text(data.total);
          });
          return false;
    }
    var interval = setInterval(fun, 1000);
</script>

<p style="font-size:30px;text-align:center;" id="total"></p>
```

This is my ajax code. Now the backend return this:

```
<span style='color:red;'>-93</span> | <span style='color:red;'>-15260</span> | 0.01 -- 12:24:40
```

But instead of changing color of "-93" and "-15260". Ajax is printing the whole text as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use .text method here. Use .html method

```
function fun() {
      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_add_numbers', {}, function(data) {
        $("#totalprofit").html(data.total);
      });
      return false;
}
var interval = setInterval(fun, 1000);
```

To learn more about the methods see this

- https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_text.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp